# Additional term in the derivative of error function

Tags: calculus

Why is the derivative of the error function not subtracted by $2/\sqrt{\pi}$, my work:

$$ erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt $$

$$ \Rightarrow erf'(x) = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt  $$

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus the derivatives and integral cancel out

$$ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-t^2} \bigg|_0^x $$

$$  = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left[ e^{-x^2} - e^{0} \right] $$

$$  = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left[ e^{-x^2} - 1 \right] $$

But wikipedia says this derivative should be equal to just

$$  \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2} $$

Comment: If necessary we can test numerically.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then for any $x\in (a,b)$, the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ has derivative $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then the function defined as

$$F(x)\equiv \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$$

for $x\in [a,b]$, is differentiable on $(a,b)$ with

$$F'(x) =f(x)$$

Therefore, for $f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$, we for $F(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_a^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$, $F'(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate back, you have to add a constant!